# Unrecognized field: user_name, while querying Via Doctrine using ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework2

here is the snippet to my code when i try to query it like this

```
   if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            //check authentication...
            $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()
                    ->setIdentity($request->getPost('username'))
                    ->setCredential($request->getPost('password'));

            $username = $request->getPost('username');
            $password = $request->getPost('password');
            $result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();

            $criteria = array("user_name" => $username,);
           $results= $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Subject\Entity\User')->findBy($criteria);
           print_r($results);
           exit;
```

i get the following error

> Unrecognized field: user_name

These are my includes

> Use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
>       Album\Entity\Album;

Edit: this is my Subject\Entity\User file

```
 <?php

namespace Subject\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity

* @ORM\Table(name="users")

* @property string $username

* @property string $password

* @property int $id

 */
class User implements InputFilterAwareInterface {

protected $_username;
protected $_password;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Subject\Entity\Subject", mappedBy="user")
 * @var Collection
 */
private $subjects;

/** @ORM\Id() @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") @var int */
protected $_id;

public function __get($property) {

    return $this->$property;
}

public function __set($property, $value) {

    $this->$property = $value;
}

//Getters and setters

/** @return Collection */
public function getSubjects() {
    return $this->subjects;
}

/** @param Comment $comment */
public function addSubject(Subject $subjects) {
    $this->subjects->add($subjects);
    $subjects->setUser($this);
}


 public function __construct($subjects) {
    //Initializing collection. Doctrine recognizes Collections, not arrays!
    $this->subjects = new ArrayCollection();

}
public function getArrayCopy() {

    return get_object_vars($this);
}

public function populate($data = array()) {

    $this->_id = $data['id'];

    $this->_username = $data['username'];

    $this->_password = $data['password'];
}

public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter) {

    throw new \Exception("Not used");
}

public function getInputFilter() {

    if (!$this->inputFilter) {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $factory = new InputFactory();
        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name' => 'id',
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters' => array(
                        array('name' => 'Int'),
                    ),
                )));
        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name' => 'username',
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters' => array(
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'StringLength',
                            'options' => array(
                                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                'min' => 1,
                                'max' => 100,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                )));



        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name' => 'password',
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters' => array(
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'StringLength',
                            'options' => array(
                                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                'min' => 1,
                                'max' => 100,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                )));



        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }



    return $this->inputFilter;
}

//put your code here
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you post your `Album\Entity\Album` class?

Comment: Seems as the field `user_name` does not exist. Did you use the property name for querying? The database field name is not relevant to Doctrine, only the name of the property is.

Comment: yes u both pointed correctly i have updated it now can u figure it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are querying for the wrong field. The field is named `_username` in your entity class. Also check you annotations, `_username` and `_password` seem to not have any so they won't be created as database fields.

If you set up your entity correctly and all fields are in database you just need to query for your `_username` property:

```
 if ($request->isPost()) {
     $form->setData($request->getPost());
     $repo = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Subject\Entity\User');
     if ($form->isValid()) {
         // snip ...
         $criteria = array("_username" => $username,);
         $results= $repo->findBy($criteria);
         print_r($results);
         exit;
    }
}
```

You user entity should look something like:

```
class User implements InputFilterAwareInterface {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    protected $_username;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $_password;

    // snip ...
}
```

You may take a look at the [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) standards. Underscores in method and variable names are discouraged by now.